# How to pause the execution of Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

In the below sample program I need that `Thread` class `Count` should pause writing to console when `count.sleep()` call for `30000 ms` and it should happen in each time interval of `1000 ms`. When I am running the program, the writing to console is not stopping. It prints continuously without waiting for `30000 ms`. Please help me to understand what's going wrong.

**What is the solution to stop the  `Thread` class `Count` for specific time of period in each time interval?**

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author admin
 */
public class Test {

    Test() {
        Count count = new Count();
        count.start();
        TimerTask task = new RunMeTask(count);
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(task, 1000, 60000);
    }

    public static void main(String[] argu) {
        Test test = new Test();

    }

    public class Count extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int i = 0;
            do {
                System.out.println(i++);
            } while (true);
        }
    }

    public class RunMeTask extends TimerTask {

        private final Count count;

        RunMeTask(Count count) {
            this.count = count;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (count) {
                try {
                    count.wait(30000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it will be easy to use Thread.sleep. and btw wait used with notify. google for wait and notify examples

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516223/avoiding-wait-notify-in-a-utility-to-suspend-resume-threads

Answer (score 0):

RunMeTask thread will wait not the Count. Both threads are separate and execute separately.